# Scrolling Issue with react-native-element-dropdown in a Form

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am currently using the react-native-element-dropdown library in a form, and I'm facing an issue with scrolling when the dropdown is focused. Here's the problem:

When I focus on the dropdown, the list doesn't move with the select input, and it stays in the old position

```js
export const PurchaseProjectPage = ({route}: PropertyPageProps) => {
  const {goBack, navigate} = useNavigation();
  const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);

  return (
    <View style={styles.globalContainer}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={styles.contentContainerStyle}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.containerPurchasePage}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
          ref={scrollViewRef}>
          <IText.Text
            id="project.general.information"
            style={styles.pageTitle}
          />
          <View style={styles.formatField}>
            <Controller
              name="filterCriteria.categories"
              control={methods.control}
              render={({field, fieldState: {error}}) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <ISelect.MultipleSelect
                      {...field}
                      options={propertyType(t)}
                      label={t('property.project.type')}
                      placeholder={t('common.select')}
                      scrollViewRef={scrollViewRef}
                    />
                    {error && (
                      <IText.Text
                        style={styles.errorText}
                        content={error.message}
                      />
                    )}
                  </>
                );
              }}
            />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.formatField}>
            <Controller
              name="filterCriteria.city"
              control={methods.control}
              render={({field}) => {
                return (
                  <ISelect.MultipleSelect
                    {...field}
                    options={buildCityOptions(cities)}
                    label={t('property.project.city')}
                    search
                    placeholder={t('common.select')}
                    scrollViewRef={scrollViewRef}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
          </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
```

```js
const MultipleSelect: FC<Props> = ({
  value,
  onChange,
  options,
  placeholder,
  search,
  disabled = false,
  label,
  required = false,
  searchQuery,
  scrollViewRef,
}) => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(true);

  const onfocus = () => {
    scrollViewRef?.current &&
      scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({y: 300, animated: true});
    setIsClicked(!isClicked);
  };

  const onBack = () => {
    setIsClicked(!isClicked);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
        {!!label && <IText.Text content={label} style={styles.label} />}
        {required && <IText.Text content={'*'} style={styles.asterisk} />}
      </View>

      <MultiSelect
        searchQuery={searchQuery}
        style={styles.dropdown}
        placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
        selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
        inputSearchStyle={styles.inputSearchStyle}
        iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
        search={search}
        data={options}
        labelField="label"
        valueField="value"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={_value => {
          onChange(_value?.includes(ALL) ? [] : _value);
        }}
        selectedStyle={styles.labelSelected}
        activeColor={Colors.Basic.grey}
        disable={disabled}
        alwaysRenderSelectedItem
        onFocus={onfocus}
        onBlur={onBack}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Issue Dropdown preview]

I expect the dropdown list to scroll to the top when it is focused, ensuring that the selected option is visible.

I appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this scrolling issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling issues in forms is one of the top problem to solve with react native.

To solve the root cause of the problem I suggest you to disable these styles

```js
<View style={styles.globalContainer}>
  <View style={styles.contentContainerStyle}>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.containerPurchasePage}
```

Just to understand if the issue is related to the parent or the component itself.

Comment: Thank you @David Leuliette for your response regarding the issue related to the component itself. While it did initiate scrolling, it failed to display the list of items in the correct position until I clicked for the second time.